# About Magick++, how to write the CMakeLists?

Tags: cmake, imagemagick, magick++

everyone.

There is my CMakeLists.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Blah)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(Blah ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(ImageMagick)
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS convert)
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++ convert)

include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(Blah ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
```

And my code looks like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Magick::Image image("640*480", "white");
}
```

It reports some errors like `undefined reference to 'Magick::Color::Color(char const*)'`. And the solution seems that I should write something like `g++ 'Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags' -o example example.cxx 'Magick++-config --ldflags --libs'`.

Sadly, I just don't know how to write a correct CMakeLists' items for it, or, for the whole Magick++. (I learned some basics about CMake. Yet useless, sadly.)

Many thanks if you could help me!

Comment: What is content of variable `ImageMagick_LIBRARIES`? You may output it with `message("${ImageMagic_LIBRARIES}")`.

Answer (score 11):

ImageMagick ships with a `Magick++-config` utility. Since you're already setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` directly, you might as well ask `Magick++-config` about `cxx` & `lib` flags.

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Blah)

# Find where Magick++-config lives
find_program(MAGICK_CONFIG "Magick++-config")
# Ask about CXX and lib flags/locations
execute_process(COMMAND "${MAGICK_CONFIG}" "--cxxflags" OUTPUT_VARIABLE MAGICK_CXX_FLAGS)
execute_process(COMMAND "${MAGICK_CONFIG}" "--libs" OUTPUT_VARIABLE MAGICK_LD_FLAGS)
# Remove trailing whitespace (CMAKE warns about this)
string(STRIP "${MAGICK_CXX_FLAGS}" MAGICK_CXX_FLAGS)
string(STRIP "${MAGICK_LD_FLAGS}" MAGICK_LD_FLAGS)
# Append all flags to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 ${MAGICK_CXX_FLAGS} ${MAGICK_LD_FLAGS}")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(Blah ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

**But!** CMake is already very good about handling libraries & dependancies. This should also work.

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Blah)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(Blah ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 )
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 )
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(Blah ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Hi Eric. Have you tried your `find_package` version on a Mac? I can't make it work on mine, and the module on GitHub only seems to have Windows stuff in it https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindImageMagick.cmake

Comment: Odd. Just ran, and found `/usr/local/lib/libMagick++-6.Q16.dylib` just fine.  Perhaps `ImageMagick-[6|7]` is needed?