# Magick++ undefined reference to Magick::Image::Columns

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

Good day,
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  InitializeMagick(*argv);
  Image image;
  try {
    image.read(argv[1]);
  } 
  catch( Exception &error_ ) {
    cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl; 
      return 1; 
  } 
  int x = image.columns();
  cout<<"your picture's width is "<< x << "px"<<endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

I use KDevelop(which uses CMake as builder), 
when I try to compile the app, it throws me an error

> main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::columns() const'

Here's what my CMakeLists.txt contains.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(hello)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(hello ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 )
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 )
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(hello ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
```

I figured out that there're often issues with undefined references when CMakeLists isn't written correctly, but I made it according to this [About Magick++, how to write the CMakeLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759833/about-magick-how-to-write-the-cmakelists)

where am I wrong? I can add any information needed.

UPD 1.
version of magick++,
8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.7

system info:
Description:    Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

UPD 2.
I just removed parenthesis and when tryed to compile with

```
size_t x = image.columns;
size_t y = image.rows;
```

KDevelop threw me

> main.cpp:25:22: error: cannot convert ‘Magick::Image::columns’ from type ‘size_t (Magick::Image::)() const {aka long unsigned int (Magick::Image::)() const}’ to type ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’

even when

```
auto x = image.columns;
auto y = image.rows;
```

it throws

> main.cpp:25:20: error: cannot convert ‘Magick::Image::columns’ from
>   type ‘size_t (Magick::Image::)() const {aka long unsigned int
>   (Magick::Image::)() const}’ to type ‘long unsigned int
>   (Magick::Image::*)() const’

what's happening?

P.S. hooray, this is my first question on stackoverflow! :-)

Comment: Try switching `int x` to `size_t x`. Can you also tell use about the system & version of ImageMagick installed?

Comment: @emcconville thanks for tip, but it didn't help, still same error thrown

Comment: The error message you're getting without the parentheses says that it can't convert a method (`(Magick::Image::)`), which takes no arguments (`()`) and returns `size_t`, into a value (of type `size_t`).
In other words, you need the parentheses, since it's a function you're supposed to call.
(And with `auto`, it can't convert a method to a method pointer (`Magick::Image::*`).)

Comment: Could you try compiling with `g++ main.cpp \`Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags --ldflags --libs\`` and see whether it works?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to compile your program without CMake using `` g++ main.cpp `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags --ldflags --libs` `` (but for some reason cannot use `${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES}` in CMake), then you can make use of `Magick++-config` in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(hello LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(hello main.cpp)
target_compile_features(hello PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
find_package(ImageMagick REQUIRED COMPONENTS Magick++)
target_compile_definitions(hello PRIVATE
  MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
  MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0
)
target_include_directories(hello PRIVATE ${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})

execute_process(COMMAND Magick++-config --ldflags
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE ImageMagick_LINK_FLAGS
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
target_link_libraries(hello PRIVATE ${ImageMagick_LINK_FLAGS})
```

Here, `execute_process` allows us to get the result of `Magick++-config --ldflags` into a variable, which we can pass as flags to the linker through `target_link_libraries`.

Also, note how I've used `target_compile_features` rather than setting the global `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable, `target_compile_definitions` rather than `add_definitions` and `target_include_directories` rather than `include_directories`. It's better to use local (target-based) commands rather than modifying global state, both in programming and in CMake, since they can have unforeseen repercussions down the line -- in the context of CMake, those global commands would have affected nested sub-projects.

Answer (score 0):

ForgottenUbrella 's version which I adapted didn't quite work for me, copying a line in from another project fixed it. Note, I'm using c++20 not 11.

I had the following error:

```
..... undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

and the line that fixed it:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++2a -pthread")
```