# How to check resolution in cpp ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16?

Tags: c++, image, imagemagick

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

try {
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Image my_image("D:\\test.jpg");
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int columns(x); 

    cout << "width: " << x << endl;

}
catch (Magick::Exception & error) {
    cerr << "Caught Magick++ exception: " << error.what() << endl;
}
getchar(); 
return 0;
}
```

this doesnt work. pls help

simillar problem here with no answers
[Magick++ undefined reference to Magick::Image::Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425126/magick-undefined-reference-to-magickimagecolumns)

Comment: `Magick::Image` has attributes [`baseColumns`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html#baseColumns) and [`baseRows`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html#baseRows) which represent the width and height, respectively. It also has [`size`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html#size) which returns a [`Magick::Geometry`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Geometry.html) from which the width and height can be retrieved.

Comment: "this doesnt work". Does this clears your hard drive?

Comment: it gives me random number

Comment: how to do it mark?

Comment: `x=my_image.baseColumns;` maybe.

Comment: it is     x=my_image.baseColumns();  thx man