# How to add ImageMagick/Magick++ to my c++ project with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, imagemagick

I am new to CMake. I was trying to use ImageMagick's c++ api `Magick++` in my code.

This is my whole directory structure:

[image]

`external/image_magick` just contains the result of cloning the [image magick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) library using: `git submodule add https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.git external/image_magick`.

This is the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` ( the one in the pic above):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.22.1)
project(DEMO)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

This is `main.cpp` (it just crops the image magick image and saves it, just for the demo):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;

using namespace Magick;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    // Construct the image object. Seperating image construction from the
    // the read operation ensures that a failure to read the image file
    // doesn't render the image object useless.
    Image image;
    try
    {
        // Read a file into image object
        image.read("logo:");

        // Crop the image to specified size (width, height, xOffset, yOffset)
        image.crop(Geometry(100, 100, 100, 100));

        // Write the image to a file
        image.write("logo.png");
        printf("Image written to logo.png");
    }
    catch (Exception &error_)
    {
        cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
        printf("Error: %s", error_.what());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run the app like this ([as per image magick docs](https://imagemagick.org/Magick++/index.html#:%7E:text=Usage,cxxflags%20%2D%2Dldflags%20%2D%2Dlibs%60:%7E:text=Usage,cxxflags%20%2D%2Dldflags%20%2D%2Dlibs%60:%7E:text=c%2B%2B%20%2DO2%20%2Do%20example%20example.cpp%20%60Magick%2B%2B%2Dconfig%20%2D%2Dcppflags%20%2D%2Dcxxflags%20%2D%2Dldflags%20%2D%2Dlibs%60:%7E:text=c%2B%2B%20%2DO2%20%2Do%20example%20example.cpp%20%60Magick%2B%2B%2Dconfig%20%2D%2Dcppflags%20%2D%2Dcxxflags%20%2D%2Dldflags%20%2D%2Dlibs%60)):

```
c++ main.cpp -o main.out `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`
./main.out
```

Then all is good and image is generated.

But I can't use the `CMakeLists.txt` to build and run like this:

```
cmake -S . -B out/build
cd out/build; make
cd out/build
./DEMO
```

Because the `external/image_magick` directory I cloned does not contain `CMakeLists.txt`. I tried searching inside that directory for the library file (something like `libmagic++`??) to use it like below in my top level `CMakeLists.txt` but I didn't know how to do it:

```
add_subdirectory(external/image_magick/Magick++)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC external/image_magick/
)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
PRIVATE external/image_magick/Magick++
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Magick++
)
# DOES NOT WORK
```

So how to properly add this library to my app while keeping using CMAke?

Comment: So you have cloned [ImageMagick sources](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick). They do not contain the library, you need to build them first. CMake provides module [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) for building external projects during the building of your one. There are many questions on Stack Overflow about using External Project functionality in CMake. See e.g. that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351609/cmake-linking-to-library-downloaded-from-externalproject-add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37776099/9142279), the solution was to add the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
#ImageMagick
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 )
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 )
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(demo ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, and it was solved by instead of using `link_libraries`, using the `set` command like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-LlibraryPath -lMagick++ ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

I understand this is not the intended use for this, but this was the way I got my project building.

Also, expect many problems with libraries with C/C++, as everyone has  [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293021/undefined-reference-to), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557657/linker-error-c-undefined-reference), [MANY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) questions that need asking.

Comment: Setting `-l` options in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS will never work with gcc, which is sensitive to the order of libraries in the command line. Resulting command line for the linker will firstly has all options from `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable and only then all object files. So when the linker will process those object files the libraries from `-l` options will already be forgotten.

Comment: didn't work, I am still getting the same error: `fatal error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <Magick++.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.` So do you suggest to use something else instead?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, my bad. You should include the ImageMagick++ include directory using the `include_directories` command. You can learn more here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html

Comment: @cs1349459 I already tried this,but here is the problem, if you look at the ImageMagick library repo at github, you can see they don't have an include directory ,they have an `Include.h` file inside the `Magick++` folder, but no `include/` directory.